# NSMutableArray always return null

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsdictionary

My problem is when I read content of plist file in an `NSMutableArray` always return null

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]] ;

// Create the new dictionary that will be inserted into the plist.

NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"walid" forKey:@"id"];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"555 W 1st St" forKey:@"lien"];
NSString *r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/download.plist", resourceDocPath];
NSLog(@"%@",r);
// Open the plist from the filesystem.
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithContentsOfFile:r]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",plist);
if (plist == NULL) 
{
    plist = [NSMutableArray array];
}
[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
 NSLog(@"%@",plist);
[plist writeToFile:r atomically:YES];
```

when I look in the plist file I found the data that I insert only one

can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the application bundle rather than the documents directory, which can be accessed via `NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Populator"];`. The bundle cannot be modified, so the created array is never saved, hence why it is never loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First you should not check for `plist == null` but check for  `plist  == nil`

Second searching for the download file should be changed into the following:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"download" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Third:
I do not think a file with the extension of `plist` will return an Array.
It will probably represent an dictionary. Try creating an `NSMutableDictionary` instead of an array.

Comment: please how to create NSMutableDictionary instead of an array ?

Comment: For each question where you have an answer that you like (including mine!), click on the outline of a tick next to the answer, and it should turn green.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

Comment: when i looked to the content of my plist file in the app folder i observed that in every run of the app the file is empty why ?

Comment: Your not allowed to change files in your bundle. Your probably better of creating a file in the documents directory or library directory as 'jrtc27' mentioned. (See the other answer)

Comment: tank you very much the pb is resolved with NSDocumentDirectory